# Is there a decent HTML Junit report plugin for Maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, surefire

I find the `surefire-report` plug-in very unsuitable to my working style. I clean the project all the time and I don't want to spend 5 min to rebuild the whole site every time I want to look at the test report in my browser.

If I type `mvn surefire-report:report-only`, the generated report is too ugly and barely readable.

What I'm looking for is something like ant's JUnitReport task. Is there one available out there already?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Indeed, generating the whole site at each build is clearly not an option. But the problem is that `mvn surefire-report:report-only` doesn't create the the css/*.css files, hence the ugly result. This is logged in [SUREFIRE-616](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-616) (doesn't mean something will happen though). Personally, I don't use HTML reports that much so I can live with that but that's not a good answer so here is a workaround based on the ant task (*sigh*):

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-reports</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
              <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
              </fileset>
              <report format="noframes" todir="target/surefire-reports"/>
            </junitreport>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

**Update:** My initial idea was to run the Maven AntRun plugin "on demand" to generate the reports... but that's not what I posted, I bound it to the `test` phase... But I didn't think about the case of failed tests (that would stop the build and prevent the execution of the AntRun plugin). So, either:

1. Don't bind the AntRun plugin to the `test` phase, move the configuration outside the `execution` and call `mvn antrun:run` on the command line to generate the reports when wanted.
2. or use the [`testFailureIgnore`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) option of the test mojo and set it to true in the surefire plugin configuration:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
       <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. or set this expression from the command line using the -D parameter:

   ```
   $ mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
   ```

I think that Option #1 is the best option, you don't necessarily want to generate the reports (especially when the test passes) and generate them systematically may slow down the build on the long term. I'd generate them "on demand".

Comment: Does it open a subprocess or just runs ant embedded? If this just embeds ant and it's task, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @jimmy It runs the ant task in the same process.

Comment: Take a look at the http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/. Build to the 'verify' phase, and it will fail at that point, after the report has been generated.

Comment: is it possible to change the html report name ? all the html reports are generated with the name as "junit-noframes".

Comment: @PascalThivent Hello, Following this configuration of ANT in MAVEN, Surefire report is generating duplicate tests in the html report. How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 85):

This is what I do:

```
# Run tests and generate .xml reports
mvn test

# Convert .xml reports into .html report, but without the CSS or images
mvn surefire-report:report-only

# Put the CSS and images where they need to be without the rest of the
# time-consuming stuff
mvn site -DgenerateReports=false
```

go to target/site/surefire-report.html for the report.

After tests run, the rest of the two run in about 3.5 seconds for me.

Comment: This should have been accepted as easiest way to achieve results and the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new maven run configuration and with goal =>

```
surefire-report:report site -DgenerateReports=false
```

This can help you to have a better report view with css.

Comment: Thanks! For failsafe: `mvn surefire-report:failsafe-report-only site -DgenerateReports=false`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for Pascal, I've found an improved solution to do what I want to do:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Extended Maven antrun plugin -->
    <!-- https://maven-antrun-extended-plugin.dev.java.net/ -->
    <groupId>org.jvnet.maven-antrun-extended-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-extended-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-reports</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
              <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
              </fileset>
              <report format="noframes" todir="target/surefire-reports"/>
            </junitreport>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-trax</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

This version uses a newer version of ant and best of all. However, I still haven't found a way to generate a test report when tests fail. How should I do that?

Comment: Did you get the way to generate report after test failure.?

Comment: Hello, Following this configuration of ANT in MAVEN, Surefire report is generating duplicate tests in the html report. How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to generate the test report when tests fail.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it using the goal ***site maven-surefire:report*** :

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command

```
mvn clean install surefire-report:report
```

You can find the report in the below location

```
{basedir}/target/site/surefire-report.html
```

For more details refer the below link

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html

Comment: wich version are you using? because with the 2.22.0 the css and images files are missing when you run that command

Answer (score 0):

Add this pom as above mentioned 1.option take out the configuration from execution phase 
keep outside, run **mvn 'verify'** and then run again **mvn 'antrun:run'**..
    Then you are able to see failed test cases as well

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>test-reports</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
                    <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                        <include name="**/*.xml" />
                    </fileset>
                    <report format="noframes" todir="target/surefire-reports" />
                </junitreport>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
                <version>version</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>version</version>
            </plugin>
```