# Generating html surefire test html output during test phase

Tags: maven-2, surefire

I'm not sure if this is a simple question or not, but I'd like surefire to generate html formatted output files(in addition to the xml and txt formatted output files) during the test phase.

I've tried to make this happen by adding an 'executions' entry for build>surefire.  Is this the correct location for this?  If so, am I doing it wrong?

```
<build>
  ..
  <plugins>
    ..
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>site</outputDirectory>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>during-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I'd like surefire to generate html formatted output files (in addition to the xml and txt formatted output files) during the test phase.

The easiest way (without running `site`) would be probably to just invoke:

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

This will run the tests prior to generating the report (but the result is not that nice because the CSS won't be generated, you'd have to run `site` for that).

> I've tried to make this happen by adding an 'executions' entry for build>surefire. Is this the correct location for this? If so, am I doing it wrong?

If you really want to bind the `surefire-report` plugin to the `test` phase, my suggestion would be to use the `report-only` goal (because it won't rerun the tests, see [SUREFIRE-257](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-257)), like this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report-only</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

As a side note, generating the report as part of the site:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report-only</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

And running

```
mvn test site
```

doesn't seem to be that much slower (I was using Maven 3, with this report only) and produces a much nicer result. This might not be an option if you have a complex site setup though (at least not without making things more complex by introducing profiles).

#### Related question

- [Is there a decent HTML Junit report plugin for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846493/is-there-a-decent-html-junit-report-plugin-for-maven)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have no doubt your answer is correct, but for some reason it's not writing it to the disk.  I'll have to do some more debugging when I get the chance..

Comment: mvn surefire-report:report is actually run under the site phase. This means a full rebuild (as site isn't part of the general lifecycle) if you are trying to generate reports for your release:deploy cycle's testing. But deploy:release may bump poms, and then things get a bit cranky :-)

Comment: After `mvn surefire-report:report-only` don't forget to execute this `mvn site -DgenerateReports=false` to generate the required css/image/js files to make the report look pretty