# How to execute maven plugin in given phase

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to aggregate all surefire reports in separate modules. In my folder there are several module and I want to generate aggregated surefire report of all those modules. I could do this when I execute following command inside the my parent folder.

```
mvn surefire-report:report -Daggregate=true
```

I want to do the same operation when I execute

```
mvn clean install
```

inside my parent folder. For that I have to change the parent folder pox.xml file.

I found it can be using following maven plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...............
```

But when I execute

```
mvn clean install
```

There is no result. In addition to add the plugin to the pom.xml is there any other steps to do ? Or is this path correct ?

Thanks,

Comment: Related: [Generating html surefire test html output during test phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053474/generating-html-surefire-test-html-output-during-test-phase)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do I have to put this inside <build> ?

Comment: sure, just like in your question

Comment: I just put the code segment you given in the <build>. But when i execute [ mvn clean install ] it doesn't generate the aggregated report as [ mvn surefire-report:report -Daggregate=true ]

Comment: it should generate surefire-report.html in target/site

Comment: it do not create target folder with [ mvn clean install ]. Should I add any other thing ?

Comment: check mvn log, this thing definitely works, I tested it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48515/discussion-between-malintha-and-evgeniy-dorofeev)

Comment: There was a conflict as my sub module also has 'surefire-report' plugin included. Then it works fine,Tnx