# maven surefire reports in default lifecyle

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

How can i generate surefire reports in the maven's default lifecycle. We have jobs setup in teamcity with goals as

```
mvn clean install -Pprod
```

This job runs all the junits, i want to create HTML report of all the tests running in the project. I came across the sure-fire-reports plugin but it generates the report only in site phase it does not generates the report during the default clean install phase.

Can one please help how can i generate report default lifecycle

I tried including the surefire-reports plugin, in test phase as below but doesnot not works

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What about http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/ ?

Comment: I checked the usage page for this plugin it states - > "When mvn site is invoked, the report will automatically be included in the Project Reports menu"


or i need to use mvn surefire-report:report  but nothing i can find where report will be generated on mvn clean install, as per my understanding site phase is not part of maven's default lifecycle.

Comment: But you can bind the plugin to a different phase if you like

Comment: Have you thought of transforming the XML reports produced by maven-surefire-plugin? You could do it just after they are produced. For example, in the prepare-package phase.

Comment: @khmarbaise updates the question i did tried binding to test phase but does not works for me

Comment: @LittleSanti I will try transforming XML reports to HTML but will it work in case of multi - module project and from my parent project i would like to browse the reports of child projects ?

Comment: @AmbujJauhari Hum... This sounds to me much as a **site**, actually. Why can't you execute the `site` lifecycle?

Comment: @LittleSanti I am not allowed to change teamcity :D :P also as per my knowledge the site phase will not create the artifacts or jars and install to maven repo since once the jars are created we have a second step to zip the jars and throw them at a different server.

Comment: @AmbujJauhari I see, but it's only execute "mvn clean install site". OK, if you can't, you can't. I'll post my answer more explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating html surefire test html output during test phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053474/generating-html-surefire-test-html-output-during-test-phase)

Answer (score 2):

If you need the very report generated by `maven-surefire-report-plugin`, I see no other way than execute `mvn site`, because a report is executed only within the `site` phase of the build lifecycle.

Instead, if you just need an HTML-readable report, I'd suggest you this walk-around:

- Take advantage of the XML files generated by the `maven-surefire-plugin` in the target/surefire-reports directory.
- Code your own transformation sheet (XSL) to transform them to the desired HTML format.
- In the pom, set a transformation in the next phase (for example, `prepare-package`) through the `xml-maven-plugin`.

If you put the XSL in the parent project and set this transformation in the parent pom, all the submodule projects should inherit it and produce the HTML reports during the corresponding build.

And last: How to browse the child HTML reports from the parent project? Hum... I'd say to code an Ant script to browse all the submodules and list the HTML files and produce an HTML index with them. This script should be executed only from the parent project.