# Generating Gradle-like Test Reports from Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I've worked with multiple Gradle projects that generate reports in the format pictured below. I like this format: it presents the information I require in a concise and intuitive format.

**Question: Is it possible to generate reports in an identical format from Maven?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Likely [Maven Surefire Report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html) does want you want. Also you may find useful the following SO question [Is there a decent HTML Junit report plugin for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846493/is-there-a-decent-html-junit-report-plugin-for-maven)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to tweak the plugin to include the STDIO and STDERR output corresponding to each test?

Comment: Well, I can't find such a possibility. But output can be preserved with [redirectTestOutputToFile](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) option of Surefire plugin