# How to get test results of multiple test classes ,after all tests run using Junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have 5 test classes and each testclasses include 2 @Test

example:

```
    class1:
    @Test
    public void c1_test1(){
    //...
    }
    @Test
    public void c1_test2(){
    //...
    }

    class2:
    @Test
    public void c2_test1(){
    //...
    }
    @Test
    public void c2_test2(){
    //...
    }
    ...
```

I want to get tests result after all Test Suite(All test classes) run
Such As:

Class1: c1_test1 : failed
Class1: c1_test2 : success

Class2: c2_test1 : failed
class2: c2_test2 : success

tried RunListener class but I got results after test level,but how to get results after suite level. Is it possible in Junit?

Comment: What do you use for running your tests?

Comment: I use maven, junit and selenium. I want to get test results and send email whole tests result. @BorisvanKatwijk

Comment: Do you want to code a reporter or use one? If it's the latter, maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846493/is-there-a-decent-html-junit-report-plugin-for-maven could be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to implement a listener in a way that it will store the results in some "predefined" file or series of files so that after all the tests will be done the result will appear in a file.

Another option is to use the output of the build tool, for example in maven, when you work with surefire/failsafe plugins it produces a "surefire-reports" where the same information is accessible. If you use it - check the "target" folder.